# Put file into specific directory when check in into TFS - Continuous Integration

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I try to set up a MSBuild-project that will copy the file(s) that are being checked in into TFS (2010) to a specific directory at the Build-server (or share). 
I have the Build Definition as a Continuous Integration, but how can I get to the specifics files I am checking in, and copy **only** those to the directory?

(The best would be If only inchecked *.sql-files should be copied, but if all files I am checking in goes there It's ok. I can manage it from there.)

Does anybody know how to only copy the chosen files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no way to do this. There is no standard out-of-the-box build activity that does this for you.

What you can do is to create a small Custom Build Activity that checks which ChangeSets are associated to your build. Then use teh [`VersionControlServer` class int he TFS Client Object Model (specifically the `DownloadFile` method)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.downloadfile.aspx) to download the changed files in these changesets and save them to wherever you want. Remember to pass in the `VersionSpec` you can use the `c#####` changeset number format.

If you just want the files that are in the Builds workspace you need to do a few more things (checking the Workspace Mapping of the Build Definition).

See also:

- [Microsoft ALM Rangers Build Customization Guide](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/)
- [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/)

The `GetChangeSet` activity in the TFS Build Extensions should provide a great starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was quick!
That's a pity anyway, that this task is kind of hard to do (the possibilty was in place in VSS!).